# Wordpress: How Do I Add Extra HTML Tags To Existing Wordpress Functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering how I can add a title="somecontent" tag to an existing Wordpress function.

Here is the code:

```
$author_id    = get_query_var( 'author' );
if(empty($author_id)) $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$alt          = get_the_author_meta('display_name');
$gravatar     = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email', $author_id), '81', '', $alt );
$name         = "<span class='author-box-name' ".avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'author_name','echo'=>false)).">".get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id)."</span>";
$heading      = __("About",'avia_framework') ." ".$name;
$description  = get_the_author_meta('description', $author_id);
```

I would like to add the title tag specifically to:

```
$gravatar     = get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('email', $author_id), '81', '', $alt );
```

If you could point me at the method to do this it would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: This is the output of the above code, which I need to add the title tag to:'<img alt="Chris Dill" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/4f5ae5de0427c2bb8c40dddd112f62cb?s=81&amp;d=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D81&amp;r=G" class="avatar avatar-81 photo" height="81" width="81">'

Comment: Much people could not understand the question, eince what you need probably is not a tag but an attribute.  Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should get you started. In *functions.php*:

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'add_avatar_attributes', 10, 5);
function add_avatar_attributes($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt){
    $doc= new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($avatar);
    $img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
    $img->setAttribute("title", "somecontent");
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going with it, though some of that code is very alien to me. It unfortunately does not work. All of the tags already exist, I just need to add the title tag. I can also edit the core and don't need to put it into functions.php if that is easier. Here is the error message:

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for add_avatar_attributes() in /home/content/24/11588624/html/wp/wp-content/themes/vaseo/functions.php on line 89

Warning: Missing argument 3 for add_avatar_attributes() in /home/content/24/11588624/html/wp/wp-content/themes/vaseo/functions.php on line 89

Warning: Missing argument 4 for add_avatar_attributes() in /home/content/24/11588624/html/wp/wp-content/themes/vaseo/functions.php on line 89

Warning: Missing argument 5 for add_avatar_attributes() in /home/content/24/11588624/html/wp/wp-content/themes/vaseo/functions.php on line 89

Comment: Edited. Try it now. There is absolutely no reason for you to edit core code. If you look at the code I gave you, you'll see that we're adding a title attribute to the image markup, and it NEEDS to go into functions.php if you want to go about doing things correctly.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the help, I will continue to read my PHP book :)